# Is it possible to retrieve paystub data with API?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Is it possible to retrieve paystub information with the API?  I am tinkering with the API explorer and am not having much luck.  If so, which endpoint should be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No this information is not available.